# NASM x86 16-bit addressing modes

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16, addressing-mode

I am having trouble with pointing to a address and write in my case a variable of byte in size. This gives me the error "error: invalid effective address":

```
mov byte[AX], byte 0x0
```

After some trail and error i tested the same but with EAX. This compiles just fine:

```
mov byte[EAX], byte 0x0
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Related: [Why don't x86 16-bit addressing modes have a scale factor, while the 32-bit version has it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55657904) explains why 16-bit addressing modes are more limited.

Comment: Related: [8086 assembly register indirect MOV instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56759424) and [Differences between general purpose registers in 8086: \[bx\] works, \[cx\] doesn't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53866854) are duplicates, different formatting of the table showing the valid options.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`[AX]` is an invalid memory operand specification.

[The valid 16-bit ones are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes):

```
[constant]  
[BX]  
[SI]  
[DI]  
[BX+constant]  
[BP+constant]  
[SI+constant]  
[DI+constant]  
[BX+SI]  
[BX+DI]  
[BP+SI]  
[BP+DI]  
[BX+SI+constant]  
[BX+DI+constant]  
[BP+SI+constant]  
[BP+DI+constant]
```

[BP] is formally invalid, but many assemblers will quietly convert it into [BP+0].

See the CPU manual for memory operand encodings and the ModR/M and SIB bytes.

Comment: When using `[bp+constant]`, `[bp+si+constant]` or `[bp+di+constant]`, it's good to remember that the default segment for all these addressing modes with `bp` is `ss` (stack segment), not `ds` (data segment), as it is for all other addressing modes listed above.

Comment: Note that 16-bit addressing modes can't use a SIB byte, only ModR/M, which is why they're limited to `(BP|BX) + (DI|SI) + disp0/8/16`