# 8086 assembly register indirect MOV instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-16, low-level, emu8086

I just wanted to ask: why is it that when I write :

```
MOV DL, [BX]
```

it works, but when I write:

```
MOV DL, [AX]
```

it doesn't?

Comment: You haven't provided enough info. What does "it works" mean?  Please post more of your code, and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: First of all thank you for you comment, I will try to be more specific in the future. Well simply, when I press compile with the first instruction,the code is compiled, whereas for the second one an error is reported saying that the parameters are not valid.

Comment: @1.618 "It doesn't" here definitely means: "It does not compile." The reason is simple: Unlike the i386, on the i8086 nearly all registers had a special meaning. The "B" in `BX` stands for the word "base", which means that this register can be used for memory addressing (while the **a**ccumulator `AX`, the **c**ounter `CX` and the **d**ata register `DX` can't be used for that). Therefore an instruction `MOV DL, [AX]` does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

In the current [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manual](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) this is described on page 509 of 4898:

In 16-bit Intel assembly it is impossible to use the `AX` register for register indirect addressing.

As you can see in the manual, you can use the following registers for [indirect addressing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/microprocessor/microprocessor_8086_addressing_modes.htm); for all of the following registers there are addressing modes that use them on their own (or in base+index pairs):

> BX, BP, SI, DI

These can be combined to (with optional displacements)

```
 [BX+SI]    [BX+SI]+disp8    [BX+SI]+disp16
 [BX+DI]    [BX+DI]+disp8    [BX+DI]+disp16
 [BP+SI]    [BP+SI]+disp8    [BP+SI]+disp16
 [BP+DI]    [BP+DI]+disp8    [BP+DI]+disp16
 [SI]          [SI]+disp8       [SI]+disp16
 [DI]          [DI]+disp8       [DI]+disp16
 disp16        [BP]+disp8       [BP]+disp16
 [BX]          [BX]+disp8       [BX]+disp16
```

Hence your first instruction (expanded)

```
MOV DL, BYTE PTR [BX]
```

is valid, but your second one isn't, because in the 8086 (x86_16) ISA there is no ModRM addressing-mode encoding for it in x86 machine code.

---

32-bit and 64-bit addressing modes use a different encoding for addressing modes, with an optional SIB (scale+index+base) byte that allows nearly any combination of base and index (except index=RSP), and with a 2-bit shift count (scale factor) for the index.  See [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes) or the other tables in Intel's manual.

[`mov DL, [EAX]` is valid even in 16-bit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474010/nasm-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes), but only on 386-compatible CPUs.