# How i can access a variable data using a variable value in adress like [ var_+[second_byte] ]?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, addressing-mode

I got this code:

```
BITS 16

data:

    bytemap: db 0x0, 0x1, 0x4;
    pixel_x: db 2; to return the 0x4 value

main:

    ; code...

    mov al, [bytemap+[pixel_x]]; i need that byte in al register

    ; more code...

    jmp main;
```

but nasm returns "expression syntax error", i tryed using `mov bl, [pixel_x]; mov al, [bytemap+bl]`, but don't work, how the right way to do it? ( if it exists )...

Comment: Don't remove relevant tags.  Re-added [tag:x86] and [tag:addressing-mode]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to use pointer-width registers in addressing modes**.  x86 doesn't have memory-indirect addressing modes, only register-indirect.  [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes/34058400#34058400).  The limits of what you can do in one instruction come from what machine-code can represent.  An assembler isn't a compiler; each line has to work as a single machine instruction.

Ideally keep `pixel_x` in a register instead of memory at all; that's what registers are for.

Assuming 32-bit code,

```
   movzx eax, byte [pixel_x]
   movzx eax, byte [bytemap + eax]     ; AL = EAX = bytemap[pixel_x]
```

You can of course use a different reg like EBX if you want the `pixel_x` value around in a register for something else later.

Or in this case, `imul eax,eax` because the array entries are just index-squared; you don't need a lookup table.

In 64-bit code, you'd use `default rel` so `movzx eax, byte [pixel_x]` uses a RIP-relative addressing mode.  And you might need to get `bytemap`'s address into a separate register in code [where static addresses aren't guaranteed to fit in a 32-bit sign-extended displacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux).

---

In 16-bit code (that can assume 386 compatible), you need to deal with the limitations of 16-bit addressing modes: only BX,BP, SI, and DI can be base or index registers.  [NASM x86 16-bit addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474010/nasm-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes)

```
   movzx bx, byte [pixel_x]
   movzx ax, byte [bytemap + bx]      ; AL = AX = bytemap[pixel_x]
```

If (unlikely) your code needs to run on 8086 to 286, you need to emulate movzx.

On modern x86 in 16-bit mode, using EBX and EAX as the destinations for `movzx` might help performance, but costs code size.  If you're writing 16-bit code, you probably don't care about speed, just code-size.  If performance mattered, you'd switch to protected mode or long mode.

---

**`movzx` is the best / most-efficient way to load a single byte**, zero-extending to a full register to avoid partial-register performance problems like false dependencies.  Only use `mov al, [mem]` when you actually *want* to merge into the low byte of EAX/RAX.

For byte *stores*, you still just read the partial register like `mov [mem], al`.

Reading partial regs is fine, just generally avoid writing them when you can use `movzx` instead.  Something like `add al, [mem]` is also efficient on most CPUs.  [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)

In general it's not a disaster to use partial registers, just avoid it when you easily can by using `movzx` or `movsx` instead of `mov`.

Comment: But how i can get the `eax` value as a byte? cause when i try to move `eax` to a 1 byte mem or register like `al` i can't use `mov byte [my_byte], eax` or `mov al, eax`, cause i need that byte in `al` to can draw in memory adress. buts thanks by the answer :)

Comment: @PatrickSant: For stores you still use `mov [mem], al`.  Reading partial registers is fine.