# Difference between (sp) and [sp] in assembly

Tags: assembly, syntax, nasm, x86-16

I was experimenting with the NASM assembler, when I came across a problem:

```
mov (sp),bx
mov [sp],bx
```

The first instruction is assembled properly while the second one is not, and gives me the error:

> error: invalid effective address

Why is this? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: `[]` means memory reference, `()` are just normal arithmetic parentheses which nasm allows for whatever reason. As such your first instruction is just `mov sp, bx` which is valid, but `[sp]` is not because 16 bit mode does not support that form of effective address.

Comment: assembly language is defined by the assembler the tool not the target (x86) nor style (AT&T vs intel), the assembler defines the language and certainly with x86 over time nuances specific to indirect addressing have evolved/changed, lots of mips educated folks are forcing mips assembler style/habits onto other targets as they develop new tools for those targets.  so its a mismash of syntax and is very tool specific so you can will see (blah) or [blah] mean indirect addressing depending on the tool and its implemented assembly language.

Comment: some specific version of nasm being a specific tool has a specific language or set of language options that you must conform to, it is a nasm thing not an x86/intel/AT&T thing.  have to read the manual or in the case of nasm possibly the source code to find out all the nuances and options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(%sp)` would be an AT&T syntax addressing mode.  (Invalid because 16-bit addressing modes can't use SP directly, only `BP|BX + SI|DI`  [NASM x86 16-bit addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474010/nasm-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes);  that's also the reason `mov [sp], bx` is invalid.)

In NASM syntax, square brackets `[]` mean a memory operand.

---

In NASM, the parens `()` around SP are removed just like any compile-time expression,
**so `mov (sp), bx` assembles to  `89DC  mov sp,bx`.**  Try it yourself by assembling and using `ndisasm` on the output.  (Or assemble into `-felf32` and use `objdump`)

This is a mov between two registers, overwriting the stack pointer.  Very likely not what you want, and totally different from storing to memory with `mov [bp], bx` or whatever.

In NASM, you might use parens when writing something like `mov ax, (1+3) * 4` so NASM's expression parser handles parens, and apparently having a register name inside parens doesn't change anything.

**I only mentioned AT&T syntax at the top of this answer because that and Plan9/Go syntax are the only time you'd normally put a register name inside parens; it's just confusing in NASM syntax; don't do it.**

Comment: So does 32 bit mode allow something like mov ebx,[esp] or mov [esp],ebx?

Comment: @SuraajKS: yes.  [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](//stackoverflow.com/q/34058101).  That would be a load, not a store.  (That's also allowed in 16-bit mode (on a 386 or higher), and could be useful if you know SP is zero-extended into ESP, if you don't want to set up BP as a frame pointer).  Segment limits still apply.)

Comment: Segment limits meaning? As set up by the descriptor tables (GDT)??

Comment: @SuraajKS [Segment size in x86 real mode](//stackoverflow.com/q/17786357) explains that using 32-bit addressing modes doesn't bypass the 64k segment limit.  Real mode doesn't have a GDT, but yes in 16-bit protected mode, or after switching back to real mode from protected mode, the segment limit loaded from the GDT by `mov ss, something` still applies.