# What do parentheses surrounding a register mean?

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, att, addressing-mode

What exactly is the difference resulting from a register being surrounded in parentheses in an operation?

For example:

```
movl (%edx), %eax
```

versus

```
movl %edx, %eax
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629710/difference-between-sp-and-sp-in-assembly

Comment: It's indirect addressing mode. where the value stored under in register %edx will be treated as memory address and the value stored in that address will be copied to %eax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Means "the memory at the address that's stored in the register".

Answer (score 1):

Move from one register to another, <strike>eax to edx</strike> edx to eax.

```
movl %edx, %eax
```

<strike>Move from eax to memory address contained in edx.</strike>
Move from memory address contained in edx to eax.

```
movl (%edx), %eax
```

How you could find out by youself: search for 'x86 assembly syntax' 
[This page](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html) was one of the results.

Comment: Are you sure you got that right? The AT&T syntax is `mov source, destination`. So your first example would move the value from the `edx` register to the `eax` register. I'm assuming AT&T syntax because the Intel syntax doesn't prefix the registers with `%`.

Comment: @JimMischel right, thank you for correcting.

Comment: he's asking for GAS (ATT) and you passed a link to MASM. Syntax is different

Comment: the link was "one of the search results". the idea is that one could search before asking, so that they could find answers independently without waiting for ready made answers. please feel free to post a better link.