# Using square brackets in x86

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I want to get 2 different things:
(1) the (value at bp) **plus** 16 (mathematical addition) something similar to: `mov ax, [bp] + 16`
(2) the value of bp+16 (the address bp+16)

in order to get **(1)** I tried:

```
mov ax, bp+16
```

But it gave an error.

for **(2)** I tried:

```
mov ax, [bp+16]
```

Which worked. (I hope I did it correctly)..

---

Why can't assembly understand the evaluation of:

```
mov ax, bp+16
```

But can understand:

```
mov ax, [bp+16]
```

because addition is not defined using the `+` sign, so what happens behind the scenes there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no form of `mov` that does math to produce a new value for the destination register that wasn't in a source register or memory operand.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mov.  The value you want in AX has to be an immediate, or contained directly in a register or in memory at some address.

If you want the value `bp+16` instead of the memory at that address, **use `lea ax, [bp+16]`** instead of `mov`.  Load Effective Address does the address calculation and then puts that address in the destination register, instead of loading from it.  [LEA is just a math instruction that uses memory-operand syntax and machine-encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers/46597375#46597375).  It's convenient as a copy-and-add.  (Or with 32-bit addressing modes, also shifting.)

(In terms of full seg:off x86 addressing, LEA only does the "offset" part, the "effective address"; it doesn't add the segment base so SS:BP vs. DS:DI or whatever is irrelevant.)

Doing `mov ax, [bp+16]` is valid because `[]` means dereference as a memory operand, and [x86 16-bit addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474010/nasm-x86-16-bit-addressing-modes) support register + displacement.

Comment: So basically `lea ax, [bp+16]` is for the case (1) (which is: storing in ax the value of bp, then adding 16) ? thank you sir.

Comment: @StackOMeow: your question seems to have its definitions backwards or self-conflicting.  You wrote "(1) the value *at* bp plus 16".  "at" would imply using it as a memory operand.  But yes, LEA is just a math instruction that uses memory-operand syntax and machine-encoding.

Comment: If I were to try and write  (1) as a bad assembly code it would be `mov ax, [bp] + 16` (so moving the content that at address bp , then adding to that number 16)

Comment: @StackOMeow: Oh, I see what you want now.  x86 can't do that with one instruction.  You could `mov ax, 16` / `add ax, [bp]`, but that's not better than `mov ax, [bp]` / `add ax, 16`.  You should use that `[bp] + 16` notation to clarify your question.

Comment: `lea` is the one exception to the rule. It doesn't dereference anything at all. I don't know why this is, and it's very misleading, but when you do `lea ax,[bp+16]` you get the same register state as doing `mov ax,bp` followed by `add ax,16` except the flags are the same after the `lea` as they were before. Either way, no values in RAM were changed, only registers.

Comment: @puppydrum64: It's not "misleading" if you know what Load Effective Address means.  As for why it exists, probably because the CPU can already decode the machine-code format for addressing modes, so it was cheap to implement by just doing something different with the result of address-generation.  Stephen Morse (architect of the 8086 ISA) explains the design intent in his book, The 8086 Primer, available for free on his web site.  https://stevemorse.org/8086/ page 41 and 42.  He describes it as being designed to get pointers to variables.

Comment: A better way to think of it is just a math instruction which takes advantage of the machine code's ability to encode these operations (and in 386, also a shift).  There's no need for the address to be valid, and in fact `lea bx, [static_var]` (4 bytes) is inefficient vs. `mov bx, OFFSET static_var` (3 bytes) so it's not good for taking the addresses of static locations without an index.  It's useful for addresses of stack variables or array elements, though.