# How to update character of string in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, fasm

I have done my research and stumbled upon many solutions to change some characters of the string. I am trying to print a hex code in it's string form. But I have tried all the solutions but it won't compile on "Flat assembler". Following is my code :

```
mov bx, HELLO
call print_string

mov dx, 0x1fb6
call print_hex

jmp $

print_hex:
pusha
mov cx, HEXi
mov al, byte ptr [cx]
back:

popa
ret

include "print_string.asm"

HELLO: db 'Hello, World!',0
HEXi: db '0x0000',0

times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

On Compilation it just shows invalid expression error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [flatassembler board](https://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?t=2530):

> 3. FASM whines with "reserved word used as symbol"
>
> Instructions like MOV AX, [CX] or JMP WORD [AX] cause this error - FASM bug ?
>
> Your BUG. Only BX, BP, SI and DI are available for indexing in 16-bit code. FASM's report is bad, but it originates from internal design. This is a "problem" of 8086 design and 16-bit code. Using more registers like EAX etc. for addressing is a privilege of 32-bit code on 80386 and later CPU's.

Not every register 16-bit register can be used as an address register, only the following combinations are allowed:

- Only displacement: `[displacement]`
- Only base register: `[BX+displacement]`
- Only base pointer: `[BP+displacement]`
- Only index register `[SI+displacement]` or `[DI+displacement]`
- Base and index register: `[BX+SI+displacement]` or `[BX+DI+displacement]`
- Base pointer and index register: `[BP+SI+displacement]` or `[BP+DI+displacement]`

The displacement can be omitted when 0. It can be a variable name here, for example. In this case you could write

```
mov al, [HEXi]
```

instead or use one of the allowed registers instead:

```
mov di, HEXi
mov al, [di]
```

The register size does not have to be specified here with `byte`, as it is clearly specified by the target register.

---

**How can I manipulate the characters of the HEXi string?**

Assuming the value to be output is in `dx` and should be written as a hexadecimal number in the string `HEXi`. With

```
  mov [bx+HEXi], al
```

a character from the register `al` can be written to the `bx`-th position of `HEXi`, starting from zero. Since the string already starts with `0x` and that should not be overwritten, the first two characters are skipped using

```
  mov [bx+HEXi+2], al
```

The value `HEXi+2` is encoded as the immediate value mentioned above. Now 4 bits should each be converted to a hexadecimal digit, i.e. the characters

- `0`to `9` (character codes `0x30` to `0x39`) and
- `A` to `F` (character codes `0x41` to 0x46`).
  This is done in the following steps:

First the lower 4 bits of `dx` are isolated and converted into character codes `0x30` up to `0x3F` with

```
mov  al, dl    ; Copy the lower 8 bits of dx to al
and  al, 0x0F  ; Set the upper 4 bits of al to zero
or   al, 0x30  ; Convert to charcode
```

The character codes `0x3A` to `0x3F` must be shifted to `0x41` to `0x46`. For this purpose, it is first checked whether the value lies in it, in order to shift it if necessary:

```
    cmp  al, 0x39
    jbe  noShiftNeeded
    add  al, 7
noShiftNeeded:
```

This should happen for all for 4-bit nibbles of the 16-bit value in `dx`. After each step, `dx` is shifted to the right by 4 bits so that the previous code can be used again. The final code is then:

```
print_hex:
    pusha

    mov  bx, 3     ; Start with last character
hexLoop:
    mov  al, dl    ; Copy the lower 8 bits of dx to al
    and  al, 0x0F  ; Set the upper 4 bits of al to zero
    or   al, 0x30  ; Convert to charcode

    cmp  al, 0x39
    jbe  noShiftNeeded
    add  al, 7
noShiftNeeded:
    mov  [bx+HEXi+2], al  ; Write the character to HEXi

    shr   dx, 4    ; To be able to repeat this with the next 4-bit nibble
    sub  bx, 1     ; If this wasn't the forth character, repeat
    jnc  hexLoop

    popa
    ret
```

Comment: "Using more registers like EAX etc. for addressing is **a privilege of 32-bit code** on 80386 and later CPU's." Not true. 16-bit programming in real address mode can use these 32-bit registers and address modes fine. An operand size prefix or address size prefix is added to the encoding.

Comment: [NASM x86 16-bit addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12474010) lists all the 16-bit addressing modes.

Comment: the code you gave isn't printing anything, I am using bochs. Also, how can I manipulate the characters of  the HEXi string?

Comment: @PrakharLondhe I added a code example, hope that can answer the question.